Why doesn't this 555 timer LED blink circuit work as I want it to?

I'm trying to make an LED blink using a 555 timer. When the switch is used, the LED stays permanently on. I added a diode to stop current from going back into the 555 timers, just in case. Is that necessary? Are there any problems with this schematic?

Please ask the actual question in the title. "Is this circuit have any problems" is too generic. Say what it is,

Yes, the diodes are necessary. Use 10 kohm and 100 µF, not 1 kohm and 1000 µF.

You didn't describe "as I want it to", but if you want the two banks of LEDs to blink independently, you'll need a couple of additional diodes between the switch and the LEDs.

Please clean up that schematic. Wires should not go through symbols. Your Diode "Dfode2" is shorted. Assign ground symbols liberally, don't snake ground wires all around the schematic. Power flows from high potential to low potential from top to bottom.

Looks okay to me. The 556 outputs are push-pull so you do need both diodes to prevent one output from fighting the other and possibly damaging the chip permanently. Maybe that's happened already.
You are 'OR'ing two oscillators with duty cycle of about 2/3 and a period of around 2 seconds (both the same nominally, and the first cycle will be longer). Since the oscillators are going to differ a bit, the flashing will vary as the two oscillators 'beat'. That's with the switch in the position shown, in the other position the LEDs will be 'ON' constantly (and brighter).
Here is a simplified version of your circuit. If you run the simulation you can see that it starts off with the LED on for more than 2 seconds, then settles in a period of about 1/3 second on and 2/3 second off, then as the oscillators 'beat' the LED pattern will change. There are times when the LED will appear to be on continuously, depending on how identical the timing components and timers are, but  that is transitory.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
